# Apex Shuttle adds multple items into single column

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex-5

I am having issues with my Shuttle service on Apex 5.

Currently I have a process assigned to my submit button after multiple selection on a shuttle service. The shuttle layout is as per below:

a part has many part_names that can be selected. So the part is the main feature and only occur once. i.e:

```
part - part_name1
       part_name2
       part_name3
       part_name4
```

let's say we select part_names `part_name1` and `part_name3` in the shuttle,  plsql code should then add each selection and add them to separate rows, but keep replicating part and the other fields, but currently it will add a single part, with multple part_names per column.

The process `plsql` code:

```
begin
insert into service_group (UNIQUEID, PART, PART_NAME, SERVICE) 
values (:P115_UID, :P115_PART, :P115_PART_NAMES, :P115_SERVICE);
end;
```

**EXPECTED Result:**

```
UID1 | part | part_name1 | Service1
UID2 | part | part_name3 | Service1
```

**CURRENT Result (Wrong)**

```
UID1 | part | part_name1:part_name3 | Service1
```

Please can someone help me to get each in a separate row instead of combined in columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [apex_string.split](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/AEAPI/SPLIT-Function-Signature-1.htm#AEAPI-GUID-3BE7FF37-E54F-4503-91B8-94F374E243E6) to get the individual values out of the shuttle item:

```
declare
   l_part_names apex_t_varchar2;
begin
   l_part_names := apex_string.split (:P115_PART_NAMES, ':');
   for i in 1..l_part_names.count loop
      insert into service_group (UNIQUEID, PART, PART_NAME, SERVICE) 
      values (:P115_UID, :P115_PART, l_part_names(i), :P115_SERVICE);
   end loop;
end;
```

Comment: That would mean it can't find the `APEX_STRING` package, I don't know why that would happen in APEX 5.

Comment: You can't download it, it comes with APEX.  In older versions there is `apex_util.string_to_table` which is similar.